# how can I use an existing realm with shiro?

Tags: glassfish, shiro

I have a simple question.. can I use an existing realm in glassfish with the Shiro framework?
I noticed the class org.apache.shiro.realm.jndi.JndiRealmFactory but I have had no luck trying to look up a realm through JNDI to glassfish.. I have this in shiro.ini:

```
[main]  
realmFactory = org.apache.shiro.realm.jndi.JndiRealmFactory   
realmFactory.jndiNames = java://app/realms/file
```

how can I do it?
thanks in advance

jmann